# Why list of stories does not get initialized in this file once I run the code?

Tags: flutter, dart

In this code, I cache data from Firebase realtime data base and then save it locally in Hive database. All this code used to work in another project that was null safe, but implementing this in an old project does not work. Where is the problem?
Here is the code:

```
class NewHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewHomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewHomeScreenState createState() => _NewHomeScreenState();
}

class _NewHomeScreenState extends State<NewHomeScreen> {
  List stories = [];
  Box<Story> storyBox;
  List<String> keys;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future openBox() async {
    final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(document.path);
    Hive.registerAdapter<Story>(StoryAdapter());
    storyBox = await Hive.openBox<Story>('storyBoxName');
    print('Box Opened!');
  }

  Future<bool> getAllData() async {
    const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    await openBox();
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      await putData(extractedData);
    } catch (SocketException) {
      print('No Internet');
    }
    var mymap = storyBox.toMap().values.toList();
    if (mymap.isEmpty) {
      stories.add('empty');
    } else {
      stories = mymap;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }

  Future putData(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    await storyBox.clear();
    Story newStory;
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      newStory = Story(
        author: value['author'],
        category: value['category'],
        content: value['content'],
        id: key.toString(),
        title: value['title'],
      );
      storyBox.put(key, newStory);
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateData() async {
    const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      await putData(extractedData);
      setState(() {});
    } catch (SocketException) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
      print('No Internet');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFDEBF7),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: Text("Shaparak"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getAllData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (stories.isEmpty) {
                return const Text(
                  'No Data',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: updateData,
                  child: ItemsGrid(storyBox.toMap().values.toList()),
                );
              }
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This used to work in a null safety migrated project, but implementing this in an old project which is not null safe, does not work. Can you please guide me how to solve it?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The stories list about returns null

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the `getAllData()` to the initState function.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. May be it is the issue with the dart SDK version.

Comment: This seems very speculative. I would expand the answer a bit.